# Absolute positioning not working in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, absolute

This is my website: https://www.tkeventreg.com/ehome/index.php?eventid=71868&
It looks completely fine in all browsers except for Internet Explorer 7, where it sends the sidebar buttons to the top of the page.

The website is set up as mostly images, with a absolute positioning layout.

Please let me know any ideas you have to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure but this may be due to the `z-index` value. You can set the parent `z-index` to a higher value

Comment: Could you share your code as it was the best guess which I could make without watching your code!!!

Comment: Or try to put it in a position:relative; container